# Construct matrix from columns

Tags: python, numpy

I have columns defined as arrays `np.array([1, 2, 3])` and `np.array([4, 5, 6])`.
I want to construct matrix from this arrays using them as columns:

```
[[1, 4], 
 [2, 5], 
 [3, 6]]
```

How I have already tried:

```
np.array([a, b])
np.array([a, b]).reshape(3, 2)
np.concatenate((a, b)).reshape(3, 2)
np.stack((a, b)).reshape(3, 2)
```

I understand that I can use `zip` or list comprehension, but real arrays are big and I am searching solution using `numpy` built-in functions.

Comment: `np.array([a,b]).transpose()` instead of reshape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with `np.column_stack` [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
>>> a = np.array((1,2,3))
>>> b = np.array((2,3,4))
>>> np.column_stack((a,b))
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4]])
```